# How can I modify one value in an array of objects with setState?

Tags: reactjs

In state I have an array of objects, each with the same properties, different values.

1. QuoteApp Component:

```
state = {
    quotes: [
      {
        quoteText: "When you can't find the sunshine, be the sunshine!",
        quoteAuthor: 'Person 1'
      },
      {
        quoteText: 'The grass is greener where you water it',
        quoteAuthor: 'Person 2'
      }
    ]
  }
```

In another component I am passing a new object to QuoteApp, but now it only has the quoteText property.

This is what I'm passing to QuoteApp:

```
Object { quoteText: "I am the one who knocks!" }
```

So how can I use setState to "concat" the new object to the initial object in state (modifying only the QuoteText property and leaving the second intact)?

Comment: If you may have multiple quotes by the same author, you're supposed to have an array within `quoteText` property, then you may push new quote to array that corresponds to necessary author, but you're going to need to pass `quoteAuthor` as well to know where exactly to add new quote.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov sorry I explained it badly, I don't want to push a new quote to the existing one, just modify the one that is already there - swap the quoteText's value, but keep the quoteAuthor intact

Comment: So, following your logic, which of the two quotes, stored within your state you need to  modify with the new `quoteText`?

Comment: I could add an unique key to each object to easily target them, perhaps. Dunno what would be the best approach in this situation.

Comment: `quoteAuthor` may serve as a key if you're not worried there could be couple of Charles Dickens' or a bunch of Benjamin Franklin's

Answer (score 1):

There is one of the way of doing it, map will return a new array with the modified value :

```js
function newQuotesForAuthor(newQuote, author) {
  setState({
    quotes: state.quotes.map(({ quoteAuthor, quoteText }) => {
      if (quoteAuthor === author) {
        return { quoteText: newQuote, quoteAuthor };
      }
      return { quoteText, quoteAuthor };
    }),
  })
}

newQuotesForAuthor('New quote', 'Person 1');
```

Comment: Wow! Great, thanks a lot, but I'm having problem with passing both quoteText and QuoteAuthor as props to this function, or actually getting the correct values. I'm mapping inside a select tag and returning all options to edit. The option tag has a value attribute which I use to tell the onChange handler what to set as state. The thing is, I don't know how to pass both properties from option tag to setState. Can you maybe take a look at my code?

Code: https://pastebin.com/gbiSyu4a